# Virtuemart 2 JS price recalculate not working from fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, virtuemart

I modified my virtuemart 2 product details template and I have two custom fields with a lots of options (input radio) and price applied to each. Everything worked fine until I made them to open in a fancybox popup. I know exactly whats the problem but I couldn't came up with a fix.

The problem is that fancybox cuts out the html code from the container form and when you click the radio the js-recalculate runs because you clicked a radio but that radio isn't inside the form as the vmprice.js would expect so it doesn't finds a value for update the price.

Is there anything I can do to make the price recalculate work from fancybox.

Maybe trigger it from another function. I have a click function for the radios which makes the fancybox close and copies the src from an image which is in the radio's label.

I hope my question is clear, sorry but I'm not Engish and somethimes it's hard to find the right words.